# How to join to closest available date in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have the Following 2 tables in an access database

The first one that has information from when do we received emails and looks like this:

| from | received |
| --- | --- |
| 12 51 | 3/16/2023 2:49:56 PM |
| 12 51 | 3/16/2023 2:51:17 PM |
| 12 51 | 3/16/2023 2:51:57 PM |
| 12 51 | 3/16/2023 3:10:48 PM |
| 12 51 | 3/17/2023 3:23:01 PM |
| 12 51 | 3/17/2023 5:33:18 PM |
| 12 51 | 3/20/2023 6:23:31 PM |

And the second table that has data from when we answer and looks like this:

| To | Sent |
| --- | --- |
| 12 51 | 3/17/2023 10:00:32 AM |
| 12 51 | 3/17/2023 3:35:15 PM |
| 12 51 | 3/20/2023 10:40:01 AM |
| 12 51 | 3/21/2023 8:47:02 AM |

What I want to do is to have them both joined to catch the next closest date that we answer the email, I have tried this

```
SELECT
    RE.[From] AS ReceivedFrom,
    SE.[To] AS SentTo,
    SE.[Sent] AS SentDate,
    RE.[Received] AS ReceivedDate
FROM
    [Client Recieved Filtered data] AS RE
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            SE1.[To],
            SE1.[Sent],
            RE1.[From],
            RE1.[Received],
            (
                SELECT TOP 1
                    ABS(DateDiff("s", SE2.[Sent], RE1.[Received]))
                FROM
                    [sent email filtered data] AS SE2
                WHERE
                    SE2.[To] = RE1.[From]
                ORDER BY
                    ABS(DateDiff("s", SE2.[Sent], RE1.[Received]))
            ) AS MinTimeDiff
        FROM
            [sent email filtered data] AS SE1
        INNER JOIN
            [Client Recieved Filtered data] AS RE1
        ON
            SE1.[To] = RE1.[From]
    ) AS SE
ON
    RE.[From] = SE.[From]
    AND ABS(DateDiff("s", SE.[Sent], RE.[Received])) = SE.MinTimeDiff;
```

But it's not giving me the next date that the email was answered, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Edit question to show desired output from posted sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably have one table instead of two. Fields would be like:
ID
Address
DateEvent
Category (values "S" or "R")

A UNION query can merge tables to a single dataset:

```
SELECT ID, [from] AS Add, received AS Dte, "R" AS Cat FROM Receiving
UNION SELECT ID, to, sent, "S" FROM Sending;
```

Use that dataset in another query with a TOP 1 subquery:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.Dte FROM DataUNION AS Dupe 
    WHERE Dupe.Add = DataUNION.Add AND Dupe.Dte>DataUNION.Dte AND Dupe.Cat = "S" 
    ORDER BY Dupe.Dte) AS Sent 
FROM DataUNION WHERE Cat = "R";
```

BTW, `from` is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as names. Note use of brackets for only that field name, otherwise query will error.